# laravel language key from variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Let's say I have this in `resource/lang/en/test.php` with this input

```
'testing.language.test' => 'testing'
```

then in the `index.blade.php` I would like to consume it with this method
but not directly, instead I like to put it inside variable first then
generate

```
<p>
$var = 'testing.language.test';
@lang('test' + $var);
</p>
```

but it's not working, it always returns the `testing.language.test` without parsing it from the language file.

Comment: Firstly, which version of Laravel are you using?  Also, what is the purpose of placing your 'test' text inside of the translation function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to call it as a `$var` then do like so :

```
$var = 'testing.language.test';
{{Lang::get('test',[], $var )}}
```

And that means you are choosing a `Locale` from an array which is should be found in `\Config\App.php` file

```
'locale' => ['en' => 'English' ,'de'=>'Deutsch'],
```

And you can of course use Blade templating engine like so :

```
@lang('test.'.$var)
```